# Can i draw a multiple specialization for a class in a uml class diagram?

Tags: database, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I'm looking for drawing an UMLclass diagram for a database that I will implement in oracle.
In this database I have a class that can be specialized in more than one way.
Reasoning with an example: there is the Publication class that can be specialized in Book and Magazine, in turn they can be Digital or Hard copy.
What is the correct way to represent it, considering that my second specialization have some like eleven child?

I have think at this solution: 
[image: solution]
Do you think that this is correct? A publication can be specialized as digital book at the same time? There is overlapping throw these two specialization?

Comment: There’s nothing incorrect, but you seem to be ignoring and conflating distinct concepts.

Comment: What concepts? Please tell me where I was wrong.

Comment: An individual Book or Magazine is something I’ve held in my hand. An individual Digital or Hard is not. That criteria alone tells me something has been conflated.

Comment: Book and Magazine inheriting from Publication makes sense -- Books and Magazines are _types of_ Publications. However Digital and Hard inheriting from Publication does not make sense to me, this is more like the Publication's delivery Format. I'd have Publication referring to a _Format_ which could be Digital or Hard.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**first version of the question**

Of course a class can be inherited (generalized) by several.

> A publication can be a digital book?

There is nothing in your diagram saying that, because :

- `Book ---|> Publication` means a Book is a Publication, not a Publication is a Book
- `Digital ---|> Publication` means Digital is a Publication, not a Publication is a Digital

A way to have something *closer* to "Publication is a Digital Book" is to reverse the direction of the inheritances :

[image]

with that a Publication is a Book *and* a Digital, but not exactly a *Digital Book* because Digital and Book are two distinct classes

**second version of the question**

> A publication can be specialized as digital book at the same time?

If *at the same time* means *by the same instance* the answer is no because in your diagram a Book cannot be also a Digital, so an instance cannot be both an instance of Book and an instance of Digital

Comment: Ok, I have correct my last answer. The real question is if I can have one instanceof publication that is specialized in a book and in digital at the same time, or if these two inheritances are disjointed.

Comment: I just would never promote multiple inheritance.

Comment: @ThomasKilian fortunately multiple inheritance exists, but yes this is not magic and can produce some problem if wrongly used. I also use the division even to divide by 0 can append or the addition even overflow are possible, I deference addresses even it is possible to have illegal accesses etc etc etc. Yes I like to live dangerously ^^

Comment: I think that multiple inheritance is a "wrong" concept. An amphibian vehicle does not inherit from ship and car. It's something different (a new class). There are (maybe) uses for MI but often it seduces people to use it the wrong way.

Comment: I agree with TK on this, multiple inheritance is mucky, especially in this scenario as the Publication is _more_ abstract than either Book or Digital. It might work in a scenario where the derived type was more _concrete_ / less abstract. As it stands it's a bit odd m'thinks Bruno.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with multiple classification in some target languages, such as RDF or OWL. The problems with multiple inheritance are strictly an OO language limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is perfectly Ok. Maybe you should rename some Classes, like `Digital Publication`, because someone might think `Digital` is not a special `Publication`.

To make it even better, you should consider to use `Generalization Sets`. Currently your four Generalizations are all one default set, even though they are shown with two trees. This default set is overlapping and incomplete. That means, an instance of `Publication` can be an instance of all four specializations at the same time or be something completely different. I think for your purpose, two `Generalization Sets` would be needed:

- PublicationKind with `Book` and `Magazine`
- PublicationMeans with `Digital Publication` and `Hard Publication`

Both would be marked with the properties {disjoint, complete}.

Multiple Generalization has its merits. Just use it wisely.